# Full text search to match multiple words in a string mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using fulltext search for search query. when i search two words i want exact two words match results. here problem is i am getting one word match results also. the data contains polish language characters.
My code is

```
  $qry="select * from tbl_jobs where MATCH(job_title) AGAINST('+Młodszy +Konsultant' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

I am getting results as

```
  1. [job_title] => młodszy konsultant ds. sprzedaży
  2. [job_title] => Młodszy Konsultant
  3. [job_title] => Konsultant ds. sprzedaży młodszy
  4. [job_title] => Telefoniczny konsultant
```

I have the following indexes
   [image]

Here first 3 results are correct but 4th result is wrong. the job_title contains only one matching word results. I want two search words mandatory results set.
query is also correct i am using utf8_general. Where is exact problem please help me

Comment: I am uisng MyISAM utf8_general_ci

Comment: Does the non latin character need to be escaped with double quotes? SELECT * FROM tbl_jobs MATCH (job_title) AGAINST ('+"Młodszy" +"Konsultant"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two words say `abc` and `xyz` to match and you want to match both then you can use wildcard `%` it will match just like regular expression matching

```
select * from mytable where job_title like '%abc%xyz%' or job_title like '%abc%xyz%'
```

It will give you the only records where job title contains both words `abc` and `xyz`

Answer (score 0):

For full text searching, you can have a full detailed video here. Plus a tip for you

> don't use " * " unless you want to retrieve the whole columns in a
>   table. Instead use the column qualified name like if there is a table
>   of students having a roll no then,

```
SELECT students.roll_no FROM students
```

**[Link for the tutorial btw!](http://www.uolbscs.com/my_courses/mysql_database_complete_video_course.php)**